# angularjs in ng-repeat call ng-init and assignee data to dynamically created class

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat div. In that, I want to call a function using ng-init directive; in that function, I want to append data to the div dynamically, by a created dynamic id.  However, I didn't get dynamically created ids in get_All_ImagesData function.

**I Want to be able to call this function inside the ng-Repeat loop.**

Code is below

```
<div class="active-task-body" data-ng-repeat="items in UserAssignTaskAllData">
<div class="col-md-12" id="data-{{items.TaskDetailId}}">
<div class="task-data-images" ng- init="get_All_ImagesData(items.TaskDetailAttachment,items.TaskDetailId)"> 
</div></div></div>
```

Function in controller:

```
$scope.get_All_ImagesData = function (AttachedDataArray,id) {         
  if (AttachedDataArray != "")
   {            
      var dataAppend = "<a href=''> <img src="+current_page_url +"Content/images/filetype/image.jpg"
       +' height="30" width="30" /></a>';
                angular.element(document.getElementById('data-' + id)).append(dataAppend);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Please use consistent case for naming things, and proper indentation. It will help readers of all kinds make sense of your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

The "Angular way" is to let the model drive the DOM. You should not manipulate the DOM manually from controllers like you do in your function. Write all the HTML in your template and then change the model to change the view.

```
<div class="active-task-body" data-ng-repeat="items in UserAssignTaskAllData">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <a href='' ng-if="items.TaskDetailAttachment">
      <img 
        ng-src="{{current_page_url}}Content/images/filetype/image.jpg" 
        height="30" 
        width="30" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `current_page_url` should be a property of `$scope` for this to work.

Comment: thanx for the ans Hugo